# input not submitting on symfony and formbuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

Stuck on an annoying problem and I feel like I need another set of eyes.

For some reason I can't get this formbuilder generated field to be found by the controller in Symfony.

Here's the relevant piece of the controller

```
    $barcode = $request->get('barcode');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //this checks for whether an item still exists
    $items = $em->getRepository('Bundlename:Items\Item')
        ->itemsNotDisposedByBarcode($barcode);


    if ($items) { .... do stuff ...}

    else { $this->get('bundle.flashbag')
            ->addError('Item not found.');
```

Nothing ever seems to be found.

I tested this by running the conditional off of `$barcode` so it's pretty certainly the twig or the form (in other words, I'm pretty certain that it's not `itemsNotDisposedByBarcode`, there appears to be nothing wrong with the query)

Here's what the formbuilder looks like:

```
class DisposeItemBarcodeType extends AbstractType
{
protected $editors = array();

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('barcode','text',
              array('required' => false));
}

public function getName()
  {
    return 'bundle_items_item';
  }
}
```

I keep thinking it might be the twig somehow, however it looks fine to my eyes;  not sure if it's the formbuilder, or if I need to hack this apart and just use a regular form.   Here's what I have for this:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('bundle_item_dispose_post'),'attr': {'id': 'dispose-item-form','novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}

<section>
    <div class="panel-body" id="barcode">
        {{ form_row(form.barcode, {'attr': {'name':'barcode','class': 'barcode-field', 'autofocus': true}})}}
    </div>
```

I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious but my eyes are not seeing it.

=== 
**Edit: solved with help from below**

Turns out formbuilder does some tokening, so I just needed to do this:

```
$barcode = $postData['bundle_items_item']['barcode'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you wanna retrieve a POST variable not a GET, to get this try this please:

```
$postData = $request->request->all();
$barcode = $postData['barcode'];
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had even gone that direction with `$barcode = $request->request->get('barcode');`   that seems to have done the trick at least here (on to next error lol)

Comment: actually nope.  I just realized it's not recognizing barcode in that second line, which seems to be a problem with the above twig.  Can you see what it's not seeing barcode?  Is it something with the formbuilder?  this seems nuts to me.

Comment: try to var_dump($postData) to see what there is inside

Comment: ok, now this is strange.   It's there:  `array(2){ ["barcode"]=> string(13) "9781474289085" ["_token"]=> string(40) "fc2716b4da2abb415d389fc391374ca4b88aee9c" } ["disposal_type"]=> string(6) "Jobber" } `  It looks like there may be something strange about how formbuilder assigns tokens?

Comment: For me is correct and you can get barcode with $postData['barcode'];

Comment: That's exactly what I had thought, which is why I'm confused about why I'm getting `Undefined index: barcode` when I try

Comment: Actually I just got it with your help.  Looking at that a more detailed error in app_dev, I apparently realized that formbuilder creates a token, so I just needed to dig a little deeper.   It worked with this: `$barcode = $postData['bundle_items_item']['barcode'];`   Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to help you! :D